# Closest points on two parabolas in 3D

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

Two parabolas are given in parametric form

$r_1 = r_{01} + v_1 \ t_1 + v_2 \ t_1^2 $

$r_2 = r_{02} + w_1 \ t_2 + w_2 \ t_2^2 $

where $r_{01}, v_1, v_2, r_{02}, w_1, w_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$

It is required to find $t_1$ and $t_2$ that will result in $r_1$ and $r_2$ being as close as possible.

**My attempt**

The squared distance function is

$ f = (r_1 - r_2) \cdot (r_1 - r_2) $

Differentiating with respect to $t_1$ and $t_2$, and setting them to $0$, gives the following two equations

$ (r_1 - r_2) \cdot (v_1 + 2 t_1 v_2 ) = 0 $

$ (r_1 - r_2) \cdot (w_1 + 2 t_2 w_2) = 0 $

These two equations involve $t_1, \ t_1^2, \ t_2, \ t_2^2, \ t_1^2 t_2 , \ t_1 t_2^2, \ t_1^3, \ t_2^3 $

So probably the best way to solve them for $t_1$ and $t_2$ is numerically, through the Newton-Raphson method.  That is exactly what I did, and I got the solution in $5$ iterations which is typical for nonlinear systems of equations with $2$ variables.

The code I used is listed in my solution below.

Any comments, hints, or alternative solutions are welcome and highly appreciated.

Comment: This is not quite how it works. Or rather, quite not. Programming questions (though you don't seem to have any) are better asked on programming SE sites. As for the math part, what is it that you want to know? That there is no nice analytical formula and one has to resort to numerical methods (which you seem to have figured out yourself anyway)? Well, yes, that's right.

Comment: I am just sharing a problem that I faced, and my approach to solve it.  The question is posted so that readers with alternative (possibly better) solutions can share their ideas.  This question is a valid mathematical question.  My numerical approach has nothing to do with programming.  This is very basic programming and cannot be compared to the current complexity of programming and software development at a professional level.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that I used to implement the Newton-Raphson iteration.  It is written in Microsoft Excel VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) script.

```
Public Sub closest_points_on_two_parabolas_3D()

'(r01 - r02 + t1 v1 + t1^2 v2 - t2 w1 - t2^2 w2 ) . (v1 + 2 t1 v2) = 0

'(r01 - r02 + t1 v1 + t1^2 v2 - t2 w1 - t2^2 w2 ) . (w1 + 2 t2 w2) = 0


Dim v1(3), v2(3), w1(3), w2(3), r01(3), r02(3) As Double

Dim x(2), y(2), jac(2, 3) As Double

r01(1) = 0
r01(2) = 5
r01(3) = 6

r02(1) = 7
r02(2) = 10
r02(3) = 1

For i = 1 To 3
v1(i) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
v2(i) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)
w1(i) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3)
w2(i) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4)
Next i

x(1) = 0
x(2) = 0
success = 0

For ic = 1 To 200

Call find_y_two_parabolas(r01, v1, v2, r02, w1, w2, x, y)


If norm(y, 2) < 0.0000001 Then

success = 1
MsgBox ("Converged in " + Str(ic - 1))
Exit For

End If

Call find_jac_two_parabolas(r01, v1, v2, r02, w1, w2, x, jac)

For i = 1 To 2
jac(i, 3) = -y(i)
Next i

Call reduce_matrix(jac, 2, 3, 0.00000001, det)

For i = 1 To 2
x(i) = x(i) + jac(i, 3)
Next i

Next ic

If success = 0 Then
MsgBox ("did not converge")
Exit Sub
End If

For i = 1 To 3
u1(i) = r01(i) + x(1) * v1(i) + x(1) ^ 2 * v2(i)
u2(i) = r02(i) + x(2) * w1(i) + x(2) ^ 2 * w2(i)
u3(i) = u2(i) - u1(i)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 1) = u1(i)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 2) = u2(i)
Next i

ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 1) = norm(u3, 2)

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub find_y_two_parabolas(r01, v1, v2, r02, w1, w2, x, y)
Dim r1(3), r2(3) As Double
Dim tv1(3), tv2(3) As Double

'(r01 - r02 + t1 v1 + t1^2 v2 - t2 w1 - t2^2 w2 ) . (v1 + 2 t1 v2) = 0

'(r01 - r02 + t1 v1 + t1^2 v2 - t2 w1 - t2^2 w2 ) . (w1 + 2 t2 w2) = 0

For i = 1 To 3
r1(i) = r01(i) + x(1) * v1(i) + x(1) ^ 2 * v2(i)
r2(i) = r02(i) + x(2) * w1(i) + x(2) ^ 2 * w2(i)
u1(i) = r1(i) - r2(i)

tv1(i) = v1(i) + 2 * x(1) * v2(i)
tv2(i) = w1(i) + 2 * x(2) * w2(i)
Next i

y(1) = dot(u1, tv1)
y(2) = dot(u1, tv2)


End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub find_jac_two_parabolas(r01, v1, v2, r02, w1, w2, x, jac)
Dim r1(3), r2(3) As Double
Dim tv1(3), tv2(3) As Double

'(r01 - r02 + t1 v1 + t1^2 v2 - t2 w1 - t2^2 w2 ) . (v1 + 2 t1 v2) = 0

'(r01 - r02 + t1 v1 + t1^2 v2 - t2 w1 - t2^2 w2 ) . (w1 + 2 t2 w2) = 0

For i = 1 To 3
r1(i) = r01(i) + x(1) * v1(i) + x(1) ^ 2 * v2(i)
r2(i) = r02(i) + x(2) * w1(i) + x(2) ^ 2 * w2(i)
u1(i) = r1(i) - r2(i)

tv1(i) = v1(i) + 2 * x(1) * v2(i)
tv2(i) = w1(i) + 2 * x(2) * w2(i)
Next i

jac(1, 1) = dot(tv1, tv1) + 2 * dot(u1, v2)
jac(1, 2) = -dot(tv2, tv1)

jac(2, 1) = dot(tv1, tv2)
jac(2, 2) = -dot(tv2, tv2) + 2 * dot(w2, u1)

End Sub
```

---